# Spivak Calculus Prologue

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm completely blown away by the difficulty of Spivak. I've managed to work through the first 3 problems, but I feel I'm missing something important to solve these basic inequalities in his 4th problem:

$$x^2 + x + 1 > 2$$

&

$$x^2 + x + 1 > 0$$

any suggestions?

Comment: Work through Spivak will be rewarded.

Comment: Have you tried graphing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete the square:
$$
x^2 + x + 1 = (x^2 + x + \tfrac 1 4) + \frac 3 4 = \left(x + \frac 1 2 \right)^2 + \frac 3 4.
$$
That gets you the second one.

For the first one, put everything on one side of the inequality and $0$ on the other side, and procede similarly.

**Later addendum in response to vitno's question in the comments below:**
In general, the process of completing the square looks like this:
$$
\begin{align}
ax^2 + bx + c & = a\left(x^2 + \frac b a x\right) + c \\[12pt]
& = a\left(x^2 + \frac b a x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right) + c - a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right) \tag{$\begin{array}{c} \text{completing} \\  \text{the square}\end{array}$} \\[12pt]
& = a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a}.
\end{align}
$$
Say you have a particular case:
$$
3x^2 + 20 x + 7.
$$
Proceed as follows:
$$
3\left(x^2 + \frac{20}{3} x \right) + 7.
$$
Take half the coefficient of the first-degree term and square it, getting $(10/3)^2$.  Add this in the appropriate place, and substract it out later:
$$
3\underbrace{\left(x^2 + \frac{20}{3} x + \left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^2 \right)}_{\text{a perfect square}} + 7 - 3\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^2
$$
$$
= 3\left(x + \frac{10}{3}\right)^2 - \frac{79}{3}.
$$

Knowing how and when to complete the square is useful.

Remember this: The purpose of completing the square is always to reduce a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a quadratic polynomial with no first-degree term.

Comment: how did you get that (x^2 + x + 1/4) + 3/4 ?

obviously it's right, but how did you know to do that?

Comment: Completing the square. $x^2+bx+c=(x+b/2)^2+c-b^2/4$.  It's also how one obtains the Quadratic formula.

Comment: For a quadratic expression, you get the coefficient of $x^2$ to be 1, by dividing through if necessary. If the coefficient of $x$ is then $b$, you get the expression to be $(x+\frac b2)^2 + C $, where C is a constant term independent of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$x^2+x+1>2 \iff x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}>\frac{5}{4}$

Thus, $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2\gt\frac{5}{4}$.  We can reduce this to $|x+\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Thus, our final answer will be

$x<-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ or $x>\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

For the second answer, notice that we can apply the same strategy to the previous problem and get $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2>-\frac{3}{4}$.  Notice, that if $x$ is a real number, then squaring $(x+\frac{1}{2})$ will never create a negative number, so this inequality holds for all real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: start by considering the graph of $y = x^2+x+1$.  What is its shape?  Where is $y=0$ or $2$?

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4$. Now any inequalities you want to prove involve only a square.

So for example for $x^2+x+1 \gt 2$, rewrite as $(x+1/2)^2\gt 5/4$, giving $|x+1/2|\gt (1/2)\sqrt{5}$, which can be rewritten in various ways.

For $x^2+x+1 \gt 0$, note that in fact $x^2+x+1 \ge 3/4$, since any square is $\ge 0$.